# Selenium C# - Finding div elements text by span element in it

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I would like to get the text of `<div>` element.
The only thing I am able to use is `<span>` element inside this `<div>`.

```
<div>
    <span id="lblName" class="fieldTitle">Name</span>
    John
</div>
```

How can I receive `John` using `lblName` or `Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath

```
span = driver.findElement(By.id("lblName"));
div = span.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but I am not able to locate the element by id

Comment: Found that iframe was causing the element not to be found

Answer (score 1):

You can try: `//span[@id = 'lblName']/parent::div/text()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + 
             "<div>" + 
             "<span id=\"lblName\" class=\"fieldTitle\">Name</span>" + 
             "</div>";

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var parent = xdoc.Descendants().First(el => el.Name == "span" && 
                         el.Attribute("id") != null &&
                         el.Attribute("id").Value == "lblName").Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the text node by Selenium. Please try the workaround with JS below:

```
IWebElement span = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lblName"));
IWebElement div = span.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
string script = "var nodes = arguments[0].childNodes;" +
                "var text = '';" +
                "for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {" +
                "    if (nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {" +
                "        text += nodes[i].textContent;" +
                "    }" +
                "}" +
                "return text;";
string text = driver.GetJavaScriptExecutor().ExecuteScript(script, div).ToString();
```